# Analysing Crash report in organiser in Xcode to check for -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I am trying to analyse the crash report provided Xcode for App Store app .

[image]

but couldn't analyse the reason for "-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] "

I have followed this link to open crash in Xcode project to check which line I am getting this but of no use [Apple crash reports analysing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)

I have even referred this: [iOS Crash Log NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector: - at which line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520348/ios-crash-log-nsobject-doesnotrecognizeselector-at-which-line)

Here crash in which line is not mentioned in report

If anyone faced similar issue, please help me to find this crash or if any reference links.

Update:

```
             NSString *deviceToken = [SharedData deviceToken];
            //Some times this device token is giving null ..may be this can be reason
                 NSDictionary *params = @{
                                     @"MobileNumber":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"MobileNumber"],
                                     @"Password":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Password"],
                                     @"DeviceId":deviceToken,
                                     @"DeviceType":@"1",
                                     @"UID":deviceToken,@"UserLatitude":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[[SharedData userInfo] valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue]],@"UserLongitude":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[[SharedData userInfo] valueForKey:@"long"] floatValue]]
                                     };

            NSLog(@"params: %@",params );
            [self loginServiceCallWithParams:params];
```

> YES [SharedData deviceToken] is sometimes returning null..now after fixing this, I am not getting this error in App Store crash report

Comment: can u post code where u think crash is possible?

Comment: @vaibby Please check the update

Comment: [SharedData deviceToken] in this line..
Sometimes SharedData object cannot recognize deviceToken method..!
So device token is getting null.!. It is crashing.

Comment: what is shareddata. check is sharedata is nil? you can try try catch too.

Comment: Yes [SharedData deviceToken]  sometimes times returns null..So this can be reason for [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] crash line?